# What happens to kernel regression (Nadaraya–Watson estimator) at a kink point?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, change-point, derivative, structural-change

Suppose $Y_i=g(X_i)+e_i$, where $g(\cdot)$ is a function unknown to the researcher, and $E(e_i|X_i)=0$. Suppose $X_i$ is a random variable in $[-1,1]$ with a density that is everywhere positive, and the true regression function satisfies $g(x)=-x$ if $x\leq 0$, $g(x)=x$ if $x>0$. Note that here 0 is a kink point at which $g(x)$ is not differentiable.

We have data $\{Y_i,X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and estimate $g(x)$ using
$\widehat{g}(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i K_{h}(X_i-x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}  K_{h}(X_i-x)}$, where $x\in(-1,1)$ and $K_{h}(\cdot)=\frac{1}{h}K(\cdot)$ with $K(\cdot)$ being the kernel function.

Question:

Is $\widehat{g}(0)$ consistent for $g(0)$?

If it is consistent, how does the rate of convergence of $\widehat{g}(0)$ differ from that of $\widehat{g}(x)$ where $x\neq 0$ and is in the interior of $[-1,1]$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this depends on the bandwidth and kernel you choose. To fix things, we take the rectangular Kernel (uniform on $[-1,1]$).

Despite the kink, your function is quite nice; it's just the absolute value function which is $1$-Lipschitz. The Nadaraya-Watson kernel nicely adapts to precisely this type of smoothness (while it does not do as well with higher order smoothness; in that case you should use higher order local linear regression).

Let us conduct a quick study of the uniform Kernel Nadaraya Watson estimator at $0$ with bandwidth $h$: $\hat{g}(0)$ is just the average of the $Y_i$'s corresponding to $X_i$'s that lie in the interval $[-h,h]$. Notice that for $X_i \in [-h,h]$ we have that: $\lvert\mathbb E[Y_i \mid X_i] - g(0)\rvert \leq h$ and so the bias of $\hat{g}(0)$ is of order $O(h)$. On the other hand, we will be averaging approximately $O(n \cdot h)$ points and so if $\text{Var}[Y_i \mid X_i]$ is bounded, we have that $\text{Var}(\hat{g}(0)) = O(1/(n \cdot h))$.

So the mean squared error (MSE) is $O(h^2) +  O(1/(n \cdot h))$. Thus as long as we choose $h$ such that $h \to 0$ and $n \cdot h \to \infty$, the estimator will be consistent. This answers your first question.

Optimizing over bandwidth will yield $h = n^{-1/3}$ and so the MSE will be of order $O(n^{-2/3})$. What happens away from $0$? If you use the same bandwidth as you did at $0$, then the rate will be the same. However you can repeat the above argument, with a more careful decomposition for the Bias, to get that the bias is of order $h^2$ (if you make some additional smoothness assumption on $p$). So away from $0$, you can pick a larger bandwidth, leading to a MSE decaying as $O(n^{-4/5})$.

Comment: Thanks! This is quite enlightening. I got a few more questions:

Comment: In the analysis of bias, for $x\in [-h,h]$, the property of a uniform kernel is used to get $|E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i K_{h}(X_i-x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}  K_{h}(X_i-x)}|x]-g(0)|=|E(Y|x)-g(0)|$, and the property of the absolute value function is used to get $|E(Y|x)-g(0)|<h$, giving rise to the $O(h)$ order of bias.  Is the bias order still $h$ if for example, $g(x)=x^2 $ if $x<0$ and $g(x)=10x$ when $x\geq 0$?  Or, more generally, what are some intuitive general requirements on the kernel and $g(\cdot)$ around the kink point for bias to go to zero asymptotically?

Comment: Or, can you give an example in which the Nadaraya-Watson estimator does not adapt to a kink (a continuous but nondifferentiable point)?

Comment: Kinks are more generally not an issue, as long as e.g., you are continuous at the kink. Continuity means that for any $\delta$ by picking $h$ small enough, your bias will be smaller than $\delta$ (and you can drive the variance down slowly too). Lipschitz continuity in an interval around the kink gets you the specific bias decay rate $O(h)$ as in your example.

Comment: I see. Thanks! So to summarize, consistency (asymptotic unbiasedness plus variance going to zero) always holds at a continuous kink. But without Lipschitz continuity around the kink, there will be slower rate of (MSE) convergence due to bias shrinking at rate slower than $O(h)$, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely!